# ABP doesn't call custom Audit Store implementation

Tags: dependency-injection, configuration, aspnetboilerplate

I'm working with ABP version 0.9.1.0.

I need to implement my own Audit Store. I follow the guidelines in the documentation; I just create a class that is identical to `SimpleLogAuditingStore` and I only change its name to `DBAuditStore`.

I also read this post: https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=340, but it seems that doesn't work.

When I throw an `Exception` in my Application Service Layer, it doesn't execute my `DBAuditStore.Save` method.

Is there any config to make my custom Audit Store the default?

Comment: please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Check logs.txt file for errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `IAuditingStore` in your module:

```cs
// using Abp.Configuration.Startup;

public override void PreInitialize()
{
    Configuration.ReplaceService<IAuditingStore, DBAuditStore>();
}
```

Comment: Your answer help me to get the way, you was right but in my version of ABP I should use another way to replace service, you can find it in this post: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/983, but thanks